# Swift: Unit tests with functions that throw

Tags: ios, swift, macos, unit-testing

How can one write unit tests in Swift that communicate useful information  when calling functions that can throw?

What I'd really like to be able to do is something like this:

```
class TestTestsTests: XCTestCase {

    func doFoo() throws -> String {
        // A complex operation that might throw in various places
        return "foo"
    }

    func doBar() throws -> String {
        // A complex operation that might throw in various places
        return "bar"
    }

    func testExample() throws {
        let foo = try doFoo()
        let bar = try doBar()
        XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
    }

}
```

Ideally the unit test runner would stop on the line where an unhandled exception occurred, and let the user explore the stack and error message. Unfortunately, adding `throws` to the test function causes it to be silently skipped over (and there's a UI bug that makes it look as though the test is still being run, and getting the same result as before adding `throws`).

Of course it is also possible to do this:

```
func testExample() {
    let foo = try! doFoo()
    let bar = try! doBar()
    XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
}
```

But now a failure doesn't really provide the context we need. Add a `throw` to `doFoo`, and we get a message like `fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: TestTestsTests.Error(): file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.1.101.15/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 50`, which only gives us the line number within `testExample`, and not within `doFoo` where the error occurred. This also seems to get the debugger 'stuck' (clicking continue just returns us to the same line with the same error message) on that line, regardless of whether breakpoints are enabled, and prevents other tests from running.

So maybe we could try something like this?

```
func testExample() {
    do {
        let foo = try doFoo()
        let bar = try doBar()
        XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
    } catch {
        XCTFail("\(error)")
    }
}
```

This runs as expected, however we can't determine which of `doFoo` or `doBar` threw the error, and also no line number information. At least we can get the error message and not prevent other tests from running.

I could go on, but the short of it is that I can't find a way to simultaneously not break the unit test running (like with `try!`), figure out which function threw the error, and get the error information -- Unless I do something ridiculous like:

```
func testExample() {
    var foo: String? = nil
    var bar: String? = nil
    do {
        foo = try doFoo()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("\(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        bar = try doBar()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let foo = foo, bar = bar {
        XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
    }
}
```

And I still don't get to find out where in `doFoo` or `doBar` the error occurred.

Is this just the sad state of unit testing in Swift, or am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't unit tests on `doFoo` and `doBar` be used to check for errors in those functions? I get rolling it all into one stanza might be nice - but testing less seems the way to go right now in swift. I don't think you're missing anything other than the desire to mix debugging and integration testing with unit testing (which I see as primarily to halt a build as opposed to do all the testing...).

Comment: You can also clean up your last approach at the test, as you dont need to initialize an optional variable to nil, it does it automatically. You don't need to return after an XCTFail, it already stops the execution of the test, and you don't need to unwrap foo and bar in order to assert them, as they won't both be nil anyways, since your doFoo and doBar methods return a non-optional String

Comment: Testing throw is covered nicely here - with example implementation code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860338/how-to-unit-test-throwing-functions-in-swift

Comment: @bmike I agree that this is probably mixing integration into unit testing. I am working on wrapping a C API and I need to explore how my code interacts with that API. Perhaps you can recommend how to better do this sort of integration testing?

@WillM. You are correct that the unwrapping is unnecessary, however the return is necessary as `XCTFail` does not halt the test and we get a compiler error. I had been led to believe unwrapping was necessary, but that is a helpful improvement.

Comment: @zach oops you are right about the xctfail not halting

Answer (score 2):

> This runs as expected, however we can't determine which of doFoo or doBar threw the error, and also no line number information.

Maybe this is just an old problem or I'm not understanding your problem, or maybe you're just kind of making a statement rather than asking a question. But with respect to the quoted statement above, you can add any information you like to the messages in XCTest Assertions.
Swift also provides the following literals:

```
#file          String   Name of the file where this literal appears.
#line          Int      The line number on which it appears.
#column        Int      The column number in which it begins.
#function      String   The name of the declaration in which it appears. 


func testExample() {
    var foo: String? = nil
    var bar: String? = nil
    do {
        foo = try doFoo()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("try doFoo() failed on line: \(#line) in file: \(#file) with error: \(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        bar = try doBar()
    } catch {
        XCTFail("try doBar() failed on line: \(#line) in file: \(#file) with error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if let foo = foo, bar = bar {
        XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
    }
}
```

If you really want to go crazy with it you can add error handling to your doBar() method and that error can contain any internal information you'd like.
In fact... by implementing your own errors in your methods you might not even need to separate the methods into two blocks in your tests, just printing the error should be enough. You can put any information you like in the error message.

Anyway, I think this is an outdated issue, you can get all the information you need from the test logs - they list out all the methods that failed and even have little arrows that let you jump right to the test that failed. They then highlight the specific assertion that failed... from there it's quite easy to tell what is happening in most cases. Worst case scenario you have to set a breakpoint or two and run the test again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own errors, using `Error` or `LocalizedError` protocols

```swift
enum Errors: Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    case foo_param_is_null
    case bar_param_is_null(paramIndex: Int)

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .foo_param_is_null:
            return "Param is null in foo"
        case .bar_param_is_null(let paramIndex):
            return "Param at index \(paramIndex) is null in bar"
        }
    }
}

func foo(_ param: Int) throws {
    guard param != 0 else {
        throw Errors.foo_param_is_null
    }
    print("foo = \(param)")
}

func bar(_ params: [Int]) throws {
    if let index = params.firstIndex(where: {$0 == 0}) {
        throw Errors.bar_param_is_null(paramIndex: index)
    }
    print("bar = \(params)")
}

do {
    try foo(1)
    try foo(0)
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}

do {
    try bar([1,2,3])
    try bar([1,0,3])
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Result:

```
foo = 1
Param is null in foo
bar = [1, 2, 3]
Param at index 1 is null in bar
```

And if you need even more information, you can use structures to define errors and error domains. Something like :

```swift
struct FooBarError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    var string: String
    var context: Any?
    
    static func fooError() {
        FooBarError(string: "Foo Error")
    }
    
    static func barError(context: BarErrorContext) { FooBarError(string: "Bar Error", context: context)
    }
    
    var description: String {
        if let cox = context as? BarErrorContext {
            return "\(string) - paramIndex: \(ctx.paramIndex) - \(ctx.insidiousReason)"
        }
        return string
    }
}
```

Note:

As @ibrust proposed, you can pass #function, #line and other special parameters to your errors initialisers to provide this information

```
do {
    try foo()
} catch {
    throw(BarFooError.foo(line: #line))
}
```

You can also propagate the original error

```
do {
    try bar()
} catch {
    throw(BarFooError.bar(exception: error))
}
```

Edited:

Finally , you can also use `print(Thread.callStackSymbols)` in your error description, but at this point, there is a risk of confusion between debugging and testing. Just a personal thought.